# node.js Socketio and dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make it so that when nodejs triggers something in an irc chat that a html page (Running on *:3000) will execute some JavaScript. When I try to achieve this, it runs through the code but doesn't execute showDiv();

I'm running this in chrome with localhost:3000 open.

Why won't the div with the id "welcome" change to visible when I type !follow in the IRC which is being picked up.

Full code:

**Index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Family Fortunes</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #welcome {display:none;}
    </style>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
         function showDiv() {
                document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "visible";
        }  
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<button onclick="showDiv()">Click me</button>
<div id="welcome"> WELCOME</div>



  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>  
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example.js:

```
//http://www.schmoopiie.com/docs/twitch-irc/Commands/Action

//SOCKET.IO Setup
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

//Node.JS Setup
var irc = require('twitch-irc');
var api = require('twitch-irc-api');

//Declare Global Variable with NO attributes.
var Follower = {};
var LastFollower = {};

//API Callout
setInterval(function(){ 
    api.call({
        channel: null,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/channels/greatbritishbg/follows',
        options: {
            limit: 1,
            offset: 0
        }
    }, function(err, statusCode, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
            Follower.response = String(response.follows[0].user.display_name);
            //console.log('Returning Current follower Loop: ' + Follower.response);
    });
}, 1000);

//IRC Connect
var clientOptions = {
    options: {
        debug: true,
        debugIgnore: ['ping', 'chat', 'action']
    },
    identity: {
        username: 'greatbritishbg',
        password: 'oauth:'
    },
    channels: ['greatbritishbg']
}
var client = new irc.client(clientOptions);
client.connect();

function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "visible";
}  

//Commands
client.addListener('chat', function (channel, user, message) {
    console.log(user.username + ': ' + message);
    if (message.toLowerCase() === '!follow') {
        client.say(channel, 'Latest Follower: ' + Follower.response).then(function() {
        showDiv();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is the div set to `visibility: hidden` in the css? If so then simply displaying it as a block will not work because the visibility is hidden.

Comment: so, uhm... i don't see where you are starting a socket server, or listening for messages from it or sending messages to it.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside the "chat" event handler and inspected the message to see if it contains what you think it does?

Comment: Have you inspected the div in the dom inspector to see if it's style property gets updated?

Comment: where does `Follower` come from?

Comment: @dandavis I said that part is working, that's not relevant.

Comment: @beingalex tried that, still doesn't work. I also replaced it with alert('test'); Nothing

Comment: @KevinB I have inspected the div. It stays "hidden". The text is always inside the div regardless.

Comment: Why is showDiv in example.js? If that's not where it normally is you're just making things more confusing by combining it all into 1 pastebin.

Comment: Look at it this way. If you take showDiv and put it on a page of its own and execute it, it works. The function itself has nothing wrong with it, the problem is elsewhere, that's why we are asking about everything else.

Comment: @KevinB cleaned up my script, tried adding a button to do showDiv() on click. Nothing worked, I changed it to `document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "whatever";` The text changes on button click but not on IRC command

Comment: @BradlySpicer `display: visible;` is not a valid value for the `display` property. You need to choose `block`, `inline-block`, `inline`, `table`, etc. Browsers will ignore your line setting `display` to `visible`.

Comment: @TylerH I got rid off all that bit now. I'm going to make it display no text in the div and on command it will then change innerHTML. Still not working, but I understand what you mean

Comment: @BradlySpicer I'm not sure you follow. ` document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "visible";` is totally useless. You need  `document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "block";`

Comment: @TylerH I'm not using that anymore is what I'm saying. The div is always visible now, I wanted to test if the js was being executed so I changed it to `document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "whatever";` and it still doesn't work unless I add a button to click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing between NodeJS server-side script,
and JS client-side one.

You cannot directly call "example.js", which is your server-side script, directly from client-side.

You have to launch it as a NodeJS http server, basically with the `node` command in your terminal in development (in production, maybe with [foreverjs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)) :

Linux / OS X:

```
cd /path/to/your/project/folder
node example.js
```

Windows:

```
dir \path\to\your\project\folder
node example.js
```

Then, on this server-side script, you have to trigger the websockets events you are interested by.
*(Pay attention to the order of initialisation: `io` should be initialised AFTER the http server)*

For instance, you can `emit` it globally with `io.emit(eventName, arguments)`
Or you can also `emit` it to a `namespace`, or even `emit` it to a single `socket`, received on `io` `connection` event:
`socket.emit(eventName, arguments)`

*`eventName` should be a string that your client-side JS will listen for*

*`arguments` could be whatever you want*

[The documentation overview of socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/) is full of very good examples.

Example:

**Server-side**

```
// Send it to a specific socket
var sockets = {};
var id = 0;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Manage something with the socket
    clients.push({
        id: id++,
        socket: socket
    });
});

// And when an internal server-side thing happens...

followersManager.on('connection', function (followerName) {
    // Find the given socket in any way
    var socket = clients.find(function (client) {
        return client.id == 1;
    }, this);
    // Then use this special socket
    socket.emit('followers.new', followerName);
});

// Note that Array.prototype.find is an experimental feature of ES6.
// It can be easily fixed with the polyfill for oldest versions:
require('array.prototype.find');

// OR you can also emit it to all connected sockets
var followerName = 'Foo';
io.emit('followers.new', followerName);
```

And remember that on server-side, you cannot call client-side functions!

Then, on the client side (which should be another file than example.js), you only have to listen for this given event:

**Client-side**

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "visible";
}

var socket = io();
socket.on('followers.new', function (followerName) {
    showDiv();
    // Do something with eventual arguments here, such as retrieve a new follower's name and append it to a list...
    alert('New follower: ' + followerName);
}
```

Comment: Hi Flo, thanks for your description. I didn't know they were two separate entities. That clears up the logic in my head a bit :) One thing, with creating an io.emit(); that example you posted is socket.emit. I can use either in theory

Comment: I've tried doing as you've stated and it's not executing on the webpage I have open.    
    
Index.html: http://pastebin.com/zsa0ZA0C    
JS file: http://pastebin.com/Z3X4Ctz2    

I did however get slightly confused with how you used socket.emit instead of io.emit?

Comment: This is a big difference, actually. ````io.emit()```` will emit the event to all connected sockets ; However ````socket.emit()```` will emit the event to only a specific socket. This socket var is the one you get from ````io.on('connection', function (socket) { /* here we are... */ });````

Comment: Would you be willing to help me in chat? I'm more than happy to mark this answer correct after :) You've been a great help explaining but I'm slightly confused about a few minor things. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80086/js-help-room

Comment: Thanks Flo for sitting down and going through this with me.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lot of thing wrong I think but I will try to help you with some advice.

First you don't start socket.io the right way I think.

```
// This code is on server
// Create express app
var app = require('express')();
// Get http server
var server = require('http').Server(app);
// Create socket.io server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Second you don't emit socket.io event on server
For me you have to do this in client listener

```
// This code is on server
// To send an event from server to client you have to use io
io.emit('follow');
```

Third, you don't receive event on the client

```
// This code is on client
// To receive an event on client you have to use object return by io
var socket = io();
socket.on('follow', function() {
  showDiv();
}
```

Comment: Not sure this bit requires changing: `//SOCKET.IO Setup
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);`

as it's the same format but works along side with the module i'm using

Comment: Yeah maybe but for the rest it's true

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the CSS for the div `#welcome` doesn't have

```
visibility: hidden;
```

As simply displaying it as a block will not work as it is effectively still hidden in the CSS.

If it is hidden then you can add another line to your Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('welcome').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Also check that the height and width are set etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly plausible reason for the div not to show.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but OP doesn't have `visibility: hidden` anywhere in his code.

Comment: It's pretty obvious he has a lot of things to change in the code. It's better to focus on that, instead of the possibility that something is present, despite not being shown. Maybe suggest to JavaScript?